# win32api no dll error python

Tags: python, winapi, dll

I've searched for answers and tried most of them but none have fixed my problem. I have a pyton script written in Python 3.4. I have import win32api. Upon execution I get:

```
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Upon researching I found that this can happen for many reasons, not running post-install script, not installing the correct architecture, etc. I installed the amd64 version and I ran the post install script. I don't know what else to do, but I need this to work because I need to print a document from my application.

I'm running windows 8 64 bit under Pentium processor (not AMD) but it was either amd or 32 bit on the sourceforge page. I'm running python 3.4 with 64 bit installed.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/ under build 219

Comment: Check out [this page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32) and see if the Py3.4-amd64 version works for you. I've had really good luck with the packages there.

Comment: Never mind, I just tried it and got the same error. Strange...

Comment: So the unofficial page didn't work for you either?

Comment: @MattDMo, I figured it out!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is so simple no one saw it. You must import pythoncom library first:

```
import pythoncom
import win32api
import win32print
```

I hope this helps someone else.